# Taper/fade CSS box shadow?

Tags: css

I've got a CSS drop down menu that I'm trying to build, and the background of the drop down has a faded/tapered box shadow:

[image]

I'm having trouble pulling off how to get the box shadow to actually taper/fade off.

Here's where I'm at right now: http://jsfiddle.net/Shpigford/f9aKR/

I've tried using `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors, among other things, but can't quite get it right.

*For clarification, I'm specifically only needing help with the shadow on the drop down. My jsFiddle is a stripped down version to keep the example as straightforward as possible.*

Comment: It's not. It's just offset. Look closely. :) The example image does a gradual fade, and the CSS in my jsFiddle is just faded the amount of the shadow radius.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're happy with the bottom part of the `box-shadow`, but you'd like the left and right parts to fade out?

Comment: @thirtydot Correct...the top part of the shadow should do a more gradual fade out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. I've added a before element.
2. gave it a gradient background (from transparent to a semi transparent black) to achieve the top to bottom fade.
3. gave it an inset box shadow to achieve the in -> outfade.

Take a look -> http://jsfiddle.net/f9aKR/22/

Edit the amount of fade/colors as you want.