# How to fade a box shadow in CSS?

Tags: background-image, gradient, fade, css

N.B. I've already looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938462/taper-fade-css-box-shadow) and can't emulate it. I'm trying to replicate the shadow on the [British Council Sweden](http://www.britishcouncil.se/) site:

This is as far as I've managed to get on [my own site](http://solaslite.wpengine.com/):

I can't post images yet but the HTML is structured like this:

```
<div id="inner">
<!--Full width div, blue bar of color here-->

    <div class="wrap">
    <!--Existing gradient background image here-->

         <div id="content-wrapper">
         <!--Content begins-->
         </div>

     </div>

</div>
```

The existing CSS:

```
#inner{
    background: #1e5799;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #0057be 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(100%,#0057be));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#0057be 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#0057be 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#0057be 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#0057be 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#0057be',GradientType=0 );
    background-size: 1px 100px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#inner .wrap {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25)), color-stop(45%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000',endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#content-sidebar-wrap {
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: The shadow you're trying to emulate is an [image](http://www.britishcouncil.se/wp-content/themes/wordpressweb-v4/assets/images/shadow.png), maybe it would be easier to use that technique.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I didn't realise it was a problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done with CSS as they've done something pretty similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938462/taper-fade-css-box-shadow?rq=1). Why use an image when CSS can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one might helpful

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/8YsAg/)

Comment: Better but still not quite there as the shadow no longer fades: [Box Shadow Needs To Fade](http://solaslite.wpengine.com/)

Comment: try new DEMO it's close to what you want

Comment: Thanks Afshin but I don't think it will work this way. [This article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938462/taper-fade-css-box-shadow?rq=1) uses a white box shadow over a semi-transparent gradient but as my background is two-tone, this isn't an option.