# How to Add top to bottom shadow box deep to fade effect with css around an image in div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

This is the style i want.can any one help me to achieve this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-shadow`as below:

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huurm1Ly/)

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Here you can also put your image
</div>
```

Comment: Actually can you see the border with color that is deep in top & fades in bottom. can u make exactly same look ?

Comment: @SouravMukherjee You mean the shadow inside the box in your picture?

Comment: @SouravMukherjee  here I think you can find your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12587813/5017179

Comment: hmmmm ! like this ! Thanks :)