# CSS shadow for :before and :after on a scrollable container

Tags: html, css

I have a container which is scrollable. I would like to add an inset shadow at the beginning of the container and another one in the opposite direction at the bottom of the container. Attached is an image of what I have vs what I'm trying to achieve.

This is the shadow I'm trying to attach at the top, and a reversed one at the bottom. Notice that the left and right side fade just a bit.
[image]

CSS for shadow:

```
.list { 
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.list:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.list:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -12px 12px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I have these two issues:

1. When I scroll, the shadows move, how can I keep them in place?

   - I tried fixed position, but then they are not limited to the container.
2. How can I achieve a slight fade on the shadow at the left and right?

   - I tried transform: rotateX(1deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) with perspective: 10px but no real results - but I think this is a starting point.

[image]

A plunker with this code in it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YREOxLXUfN7xCUQDwc77?p=preview

Comment: I saw designer Lea Verou make exactly this design in a conference, but I can't remember exactly when . Give it a try a look at Lea Verou videos posted in you tube !

Comment: @vals , you wouldn't happen to know any of the keywords, there are plenty of videos out there

Comment: I have find it !   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ikye7Qc7Ak

Comment: but look at the end of the video, the first time it is wrong !

Comment: wow @vals, you may be onto something here. You can post an answer if you want, it's close to what I was looking for, but the difference is that radial gradient spreads out from the center rather than staying consistent at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, about the scrolling issue, the solution is in the video from Lea Verou conference.

I could post the code here, but people *should* see the video, it deserves it

About the request shadow, generated with backgrounds, I porvide you 2 different options, generated with multiple backgrounds. The first uses rounded corners, the second linear ones.

I have done it bigger and darker than requested, so that the difference is easier to see.

```css
.one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, black 0%, white 70%),
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, black 0%, white 70%),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 0%, white 100%);
  background-size: 40px 40px, 40px 40px, 100% 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left, bottom right, bottom left;
  }

.two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 220px; top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, white 50%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 50%),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 0%, white 100%);
  background-size: 40px 40px, 40px 40px, 100% 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left, bottom right, bottom left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be some complex CSS

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a container `<div>` to achieve this. Something like this:

```css
.list-container {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.list-container:before {
  display:block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.list-container:after {
  display:block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -12px 12px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  bottom: 0;
}
.list { 
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <div class="list">
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
    <div> {{item}} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for the slight fade you desire, have a look here: [Taper/fade CSS box shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938462/taper-fade-css-box-shadow)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solves the first part. I'm not sure how that post helps the with taper/fade, because that post works only for a rectangle section which uses a gradient to simulate a fade. I assume this is not possible with just just the box shadow.

Comment: I think you would have to introduce more HTML elements, to achieve the fade.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
.wrapList:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.wrapList:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12px;
  border: 0;

  box-shadow: inset 0 -12px 12px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,  rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
}
```

with

```
 <div class="wrapList">
         <div class="list">
           <div ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item}} </div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you put this in a plunker? I tried the first one (:before) and it didn't seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: Well, as you see, this doesn't actually work as in my description I mention trying fixed position and the issue with it.